# Business card recogition not seeing umlauts

Tags: sdk, abbyy, finereader

I'm using a trial version of Finereader 11 to scan business cards. So far it ignores all umlauts.

Should I be initialising the engine in a different way? Do I need to specify which languages I want?

```
IFRDocument document = engine.CreateFRDocument();
document.AddImageFile("c:/temp/ctrk.bmp", pim, null);
IDocumentProcessingParams idpp = engine.CreateDocumentProcessingParams();
idpp.getPageProcessingParams().getRecognizerParams().setDetectLanguage(true);
document.Process(idpp);
if(document.getBusinessCards().getCount() > 0)
{
    IBusinessCard card = document.getBusinessCards().getElement(0);
    card.ExportToVCard("c:/temp/abbyy.vcf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to detect a business card.

```
// Create parameters of document processing
FREngine.DocumentProcessingParams dpp = engine.CreateDocumentProcessingParams();
// A page can contain several business cards
dpp.PageProcessingParams.PageAnalysisParams.DetectMultipleBusinessCards = true;
// Perform recognition with the specified parameters
frDoc.Process( dpp );

// Access a business card
FREngine.BusinessCard card = frDoc.BusinessCards[0];
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same as my code example. What about the Umlaut (German accents) problem? Do you have any comments on that?

Comment: There are no problems with umlauts. You've got to specify correct OCR language, because default is English (no umlauts in English).

Comment: So the `idpp.getPageProcessingParams().getRecognizerParams().setDetectLanguage(true);` doesn't help in this case? I tried getting help from Abbyy back in July and got no response. I used a different supplier...